# How to enable cleartype for Sublime Text 2 on Windows 7 Virtual Machine?

Tags: windows, sublimetext2, virtual-machine, vmware, cleartype

I have a Virtual Machine Windows 7 (using VMWare) with opened Sublime Text 2.
Cleartype for the OS is enabled, but i don't see it's effect inside my text editor:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: silly question - are you using a font with ClearType support in Sublime? Also, have you tried playing with the `"font_size"` setting? Depending on your font, some sizes look better than others, at least in my experience.

Comment: @MattDMo you made my day! Thanks! Just one `Ctrl + -` made everything look awesome.

Comment: Dear "off-topic" moderator overlords: this issue is unique to Sublime Text, a "tool used primarily for programming."  This fact and the helpful answer make it clear that this question was most appropriately asked on Stack Overflow, not Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, not every font size in Sublime is rendered properly by ClearType, at least for some fonts, and this also varies depending on which version of Windows you're using. I've found through trial and error that either using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> to increase/decrease the font size can help, as can altering the `"font_size"` option in `Preferences -> Settings - User` by increments of 0.5.

If nothing seems to work, try using different fonts - some may simply not look as good using Sublime's rendering engine.